# how to create Dynamic Query containing union of results from multiple tables in spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I have a query where the result is fetched as a union from three different tables, since the columns in these three tables are named differently ( datatypes are same) I alias it to fetch the result as how we normally do in a sql query.

```
select * 
from
(
   select goodsId as ID,
          goodsRate as Amt
          from GoodsDtl
   union
   select prodId as ID,
          cost as Amt
          from Product
   union
   select itemId as ID,
          rate as Amt
          from Items
)
```

In my spring boot project, I use this native query to fetch result in a DTO class with variables as ID and Amt and then I do processing on this DTO as per business requirement.

Now, I want make this query dynamic as in if I had to introduce a new column in these three tables, I'll have to change this query instead I aim to make it dynamic such that I only specify column name, table name and alias, and I get the result in the same DTO. So, technically it would be a new variable introduction in my DTO class, probably a mapping addition for these three tables about the column name would be required.

Method: ( this is one way I can think of)

Maintaining a JSON file like below:

```
[
  {
    "entityName":"GoodsDtl",
    "columnName":"goodsId",
    "aliasName":"Id"    
  },
  {
    "entityName":"GoodsDtl",
    "columnName":"goodsRate",
    "aliasName":"Amt"   
  }
]
```

Then, forming the sql query dynamically using this JSON file.

Question: Is there any other better way to do it, if spring JPA/ Hibernate features this kind of scenarios?

Comment: FYI, the column aliases on the union'ed queries are ignored, so you can leave them out. Note this means you *must* select all columns in the same order in each query. See for example https://dbfiddle.uk/9blp6HmU

Comment: oh okay thanks for this info. It would really help!